# How do web clients access vpn protected servers?

Tags: vpn, proxy, reverse-proxy, gateway, host

I'm not talking about joining the VPN network through a client like OpenVPN, I'm talking about the user's connection to the VPN server, for example:

Normal flow: Web Client >>>> Server (No VPN)

Server flow with VPN:

Web Client >>> [ Reverse Proxy ? / Gateway ? ] <<<< VPN >>> Server

I know it's a good practice to leave the servers in a VPN, so that failures of each service are not exposed to the web, because the VPN will be filtering... But, how will the client access it? Possibly through a Public IP, but who makes this public IP available? The Proxy? VPN? Gateway? DNS?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: You're basically asking for a network primer. We explicitly don't allow requests for learning materials. I would suggest to get almost any book on TCP/IP, which will equip you to understand how TCP/IP works in general.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is to think of a VPN as a tunnel through the Internet. The VPN client on the web client redirects any requests for the servers to a specific public IP, where it is picked up by the VPN gateway, routed through the VPN to another VPN gateway, from where it goes to your servers. It is the VPN client, typically on the web client, that knows the public IP that routes to the gateway, and it is the VPN gateway that responds to that public address.

The VPN does little to show whether specific services have failed or are in failover states; if you can get into the VPN at all, you have a clear view of what's on the other end. For handling potential failed servers you'd need other proxying arrangements within the network that the VPN points at. The idea, I guess, is that the proxy - not the VPN - publishes an address through which you want the Internet to view your services; the VPN would give you a back door past that public portal so you can do the sorts of maintenance that can't be done through the web portal.